# How to solve error "HeapWorker is wedged " in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am fetching data from the server in a big quantity. I am using Get method to get response and I am able to get the response but the issue is that in between of parsing application is crashing because of some **"HeapWorker is wedged"** error.

**Logcat**

```
12-20 10:02:55.111: ERROR/dalvikvm(277): HeapWorker is wedged: 10194ms spent inside Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor;.finalize()V
12-20 10:02:55.111: INFO/dalvikvm(277): DALVIK THREADS:
12-20 10:02:55.111: INFO/dalvikvm(277): "main" prio=5 tid=3 NATIVE
12-20 10:02:55.111: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=Y obj=0x4001b268 self=0xbd00
12-20 10:02:55.111: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   | sysTid=277 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1344001384
12-20 10:02:55.111: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.graphics.NinePatch.nativeDraw(Native Method)
12-20 10:02:55.111: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.graphics.NinePatch.draw(NinePatch.java:104)
12-20 10:02:55.111: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.draw(NinePatchDrawable.java:188)
12-20 10:02:55.121: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6520)
12-20 10:02:55.121: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
12-20 10:02:55.121: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
12-20 10:02:55.121: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
12-20 10:02:55.121: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
12-20 10:02:55.121: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
12-20 10:02:55.121: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
12-20 10:02:55.121: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
12-20 10:02:55.121: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
12-20 10:02:55.121: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
12-20 10:02:55.121: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
12-20 10:02:55.121: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1349)
12-20 10:02:55.121: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1114)
12-20 10:02:55.121: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277): "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=15 RUNNABLE
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x44dd0bd0 self=0x125a30
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   | sysTid=283 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1203016
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.io.BufferedWriter.<init>(BufferedWriter.java:~67)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at uk.co.dodec.ukrcmobileapp.helper.UDFHelper.createHtml(UDFHelper.java:167)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at uk.co.dodec.ukrcmobileapp.helper.XMLParser.parseUpdates(XMLParser.java:510)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at uk.co.dodec.ukrcmobileapp.Homepage$getUpdateTask.doInBackground(Homepage.java:170)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at uk.co.dodec.ukrcmobileapp.Homepage$getUpdateTask.doInBackground(Homepage.java:1)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-20 10:02:55.132: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277): "Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=13 NATIVE
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x44da1c38 self=0x11d3c8
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   | sysTid=282 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1343552
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277): "Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x44d9dea8 self=0x14d8d0
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   | sysTid=281 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1366160
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277): "JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=9 VMWAIT
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x44d9b2a0 self=0x145338
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   | sysTid=280 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1331744
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=7 VMWAIT
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x44d9b1e8 self=0x145108
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   | sysTid=279 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1262808
12-20 10:02:55.141: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277): "HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=5 WAIT
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4369a188 self=0x1343c0
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   | sysTid=278 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1208016
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   - waiting on <0x3362f0> (a java.lang.VMThread)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1535)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:317)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:131)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:790)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:823)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1153)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:200)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:261)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:305)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.close(SQLiteProgram.java:219)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.close(SQLiteQuery.java:141)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.close(SQLiteCursor.java:507)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:586)
12-20 10:02:55.151: INFO/dalvikvm(277):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-20 10:02:55.151: ERROR/dalvikvm(277): VM aborting
12-20 10:02:55.296: INFO/DEBUG(28): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-20 10:02:55.296: INFO/DEBUG(28): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadd00d
12-20 10:02:55.296: INFO/DEBUG(28):  r0 00000354  r1 afe1331d  r2 0000000c  r3 deadd00d
12-20 10:02:55.296: INFO/DEBUG(28):  r4 00000026  r5 400091e8  r6 ad065714  r7 003fca30
12-20 10:02:55.296: INFO/DEBUG(28):  r8 00000344  r9 00000001  10 ad080c00  fp 00000000
12-20 10:02:55.296: INFO/DEBUG(28):  ip ad080160  sp 46a32c58  lr afe142dd  pc ad035452  cpsr 20000030
12-20 10:02:55.391: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #00  pc 00035452  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.391: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #01  pc 000440d8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.391: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #02  pc 0001680c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.391: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #03  pc 000170c4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.391: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #04  pc 0001724c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.401: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #05  pc 00055b52  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.401: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #06  pc 00055c80  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.401: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #07  pc 00055d80  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.401: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #08  pc 0001353c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.411: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #09  pc 00019888  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.411: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #10  pc 00018d5c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.411: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #11  pc 0004d6d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.411: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #12  pc 0004d702  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.411: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #13  pc 00041c78  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.411: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #14  pc 00010000  /system/lib/libc.so
12-20 10:02:55.411: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #15  pc 0000fad4  /system/lib/libc.so
12-20 10:02:55.411: INFO/DEBUG(28): code around pc:
12-20 10:02:55.411: INFO/DEBUG(28): ad035440 4808ecb6 6b9b5823 d0002b00 4b064798 
12-20 10:02:55.411: INFO/DEBUG(28): ad035450 701c2426 ed28f7d9 0004ab1c fffe57c4 
12-20 10:02:55.411: INFO/DEBUG(28): ad035460 fffe8c30 00000354 deadd00d b510b40e 
12-20 10:02:55.411: INFO/DEBUG(28): code around lr:
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28): afe142cc 220ce008 2b005eab 1c28d003 47889901 
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28): afe142dc 35544306 d5f43f01 2c006824 b003d1ee 
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28): afe142ec bdf01c30 00024b44 000000b4 1c0fb5f0 
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28): stack:
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c18  00000015  
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c1c  afe1334d  /system/lib/libc.so
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c20  afe3902c  /system/lib/libc.so
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c24  afe38fd8  /system/lib/libc.so
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c28  00000000  
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c2c  afe142dd  /system/lib/libc.so
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c30  46a32c44  
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c34  afe1331d  /system/lib/libc.so
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c38  ad065714  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c3c  ad07ff50  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c40  400091e8  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/zygote/0 (deleted)
12-20 10:02:55.422: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c44  ad065714  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c48  003fca30  [heap]
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c4c  afe1337f  /system/lib/libc.so
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c50  df002777  
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c54  e3a070ad  
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28): #00 46a32c58  ad06ccd7  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c5c  ad0440dd  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28): #01 46a32c60  000027d2  
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c64  00000000  
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c68  42a58733  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c6c  42ad950b  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c70  003fca30  [heap]
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c74  0000011b  
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c78  ad080f8c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c7c  afe0f3b0  /system/lib/libc.so
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c80  009b8cc3  
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c84  00000000  
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c88  00000354  
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c8c  400091e8  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/zygote/0 (deleted)
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c90  ad07ff50  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c94  00000354  
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c98  0000000a  
12-20 10:02:55.431: INFO/DEBUG(28):     46a32c9c  ad016810  /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

Comment: Are you getting this error everytime or in some cases?

Comment: Every time I am getting this error

Comment: @Dharmendra Are you doing the parsing in UI Thread?

Comment: I am parsing data in asynctask and displaying progressdialog until update will completed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution of my issue 
I am using transaction while parsing the data and inserting data in to database.
But in between I am trying to get some values from database.
So that hierarchic like below

```
<transaction>
<Insert>
 <select>
<insert>
</transaction>
```

I am trying to run select query on database, while database is in a transaction.
Actually there is a solution here about [concurrent transaction](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html)

The SQL command `"BEGIN TRANSACTION"` (the `TRANSACTION` keyword is optional) is used to take SQLite out of autocommit mode. Note that the `BEGIN` command does not acquire any locks on the database. After a `BEGIN` command, a `SHARED` lock will be acquired when the first SELECT statement is executed. A RESERVED lock will be acquired when the first `INSERT`, `UPDATE, or DELETE` statement is executed. No `EXCLUSIVE` lock is acquired until either the memory cache fills up and must be spilled to disk or until the transaction commits. In this way, the system delays blocking read access to the file file until the last possible moment.

I just removed the select query lines from the code while database is in transaction

---

*Edit*

Also there is one other solution is that you set locking enable false like

```
mDb.setLockingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This method was deprecated in API level 16.
This method now does nothing. Do not use.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that a ***finalizer*** is stuck for that long.

If you can eliminate the finalizer, problem solved.  If you can't, you 
need to eliminate the interdependence between the finalizer and the 
slow-running thread.

The VM assumes that finalizers finish quickly, and anything taking a 
really long time is probably deadlocked.

Rather than wait for the VM to run out of resources and crash mysteriously, it tells you about the problem immediately, and then shoots itself in the head to make sure 
you notice. #copied from [Here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/cbc96b0bfb79e9c4)